# Publish SP2016 User Profile Service for use on SP2010 farms?

Tags: user-profile-service, sync, service, ups

If I publish the User Profile Service service application on a SharePoint 2016 farm for sharing, can a SharePoint 2010 farm subscribe to it?

And, if you have done this and have any real-world experience to pass along, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not supported/possible. Microsoft only supports N-1 publishing (that is, 2016 can publish for 2013, but not 2010).